# Blazor WASM Cookie Authentication .NET5

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5, asp.net-blazor

Im building my first Blazor WASM (Client and Server) app in .NET5 and having troubles with the authentication.
My goal is to **not** use Identity since I don't want to use localstorage and only have a JWT (or similar) cookie authentication like this picture: [Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJNb.png).

I have tried to use the

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie( ... )
```

on server side but then Im getting an error saying

`There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.`.

I got no error with

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication
```

in the Client's Program.cs but the app did not authorized me after I logged in (I got a token in my cookies).

I feel like I have tried every Microsoft Docs and tutorials out there but with no luck so if someone have a solution to this it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have project Blazor webassembly which get authenticated by Identity server
you could find the full code here
https://github.com/kdehia/BlazorSecureWithIdentity_API_GRPC

in main.cs
you should get the config values from appsettings.json

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {

            builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);

        });
```

your appsettings.json
should look something like this

```
{
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:5005/",
    "ClientId": "blazorWASM",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "companyApi",
      "ApplicationRole",
      "GRPC"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

Download the full project and let me know if you have any question